# RunProcess Does not Stop

Tags: pdf-format, latex, command-line

I want to convert a latex file to a pdf file, using Mathematica. To do that, I installed MikTex and the I can run the following command in cmd:

```
lualatex main.txt
```

It works and it creates the pdf. So now, I wanted to let it run through MAthematica.

What I did was:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[] <> "...PATH"]
RunProcess[{"lualatex", "main.txt"}]
```

... It starts to do something, but it does not end ? When I run itfrom cmd it takes about 20s to finish.

Anyone knows how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me. So my guess is that you have a typo: main.txt should be main.tex, and lualatex is waiting for user input to "type another input file name", which is what happens if you use the command line and the input file is not found.

Comment: Yes, it's almost certainly this. To force the process to quit on error, use `-halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode`. I use these in MaTeX. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451013/6302

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Very helpful.